# Numeric Latitude & Longitude values are rounded up when querying SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, number-formatting, integer

Developing an application that is using Google Maps. Latitude and longitude values are stored in the table as the correct value. However when they are pulled into a view the value is rounded to the nearest 100<sup>th</sup>, thus making the place marker on google maps inaccurate.

Any suggestions on how to always return the true value of the number ?

Comment: Stored using what data type? What is the definition of the view? Where are you actually observing this rounding? Are you using `PRINT`, `SELECT`, or is it after it is written out by your application?

Comment: Stored using decimal(18,10)

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this issue was due to the fact that the way the code was being pulled from the database. In `coldfusion` if you are going to query the numeric value from the database, you must use a `sql query param` and specify the return type of the data.